# WinForms: A control that cannot be used in MDI parent?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

During an interview i was asked "a control that cannot be used in a MDI parent Form ?" , i couldn't find much about this on the internet , anybody have a clue ?

Thanks

Comment: Based on the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,7716), maybe they expected an answer like this: A from which has an MdiParent. Also, you cannot add a top-level control to a Form (no matter MDI or normal form).

Comment: In other words, when you declare a new Form and set its `MdiParent` property, you don't `Add()` the Form, you `Show()` it. Other Controls can be added to a MdiParent Form (even another MdiClient). -- An interviewer can come up with better questions, IMO.